# How to avoid the “Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?” when changes committed? on pagination click of gridview in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, pagination

My web page contains grid-view with many input fields.I want to give alert to user before moving to next tab. My script is working fine in Mozilla Firefox and chrome but in IE the alert is also coming for grid-view pagination click.I don't want to show on pagination click.but in Mozilla and chrome this doesn't happen. How to avoid this .

Here I am giving my script

```
 <script>

    var warnMessage = "You have unsaved changes on this page!";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:not(:button,:submit),textarea,select').change(function () {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if (warnMessage != null) return warnMessage;
            }
        });
        $('input:submit').click(function (e) {
            warnMessage = null;
        });
    });



</script>
```

How to avoid of this message in gridview pagination click in IE only?
Can anybody help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the the value to null on pagination click

> ```
>    window.onbeforeunload = null;
> ```

**UPDATE 1**

try this one instead of your code:

> ```
>   var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
>     var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable
>     myEvent(chkevent, function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
>         var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?';  // a space
>         (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
>         return confirmationMessage;
>     });
> ```

**UPDATE 2**

after you use window.onbeforeunload = null; in your pagination control to rebind the alert in your update panel try this solution, it may help you with that issue:

> ```
>    $(document).ready(function () {
>      bindPageAlert();
>    });
>
>     function bindPageAlert()
>     {
>         var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
>         var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';
>         myEvent(chkevent, function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
>             var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?';  // a space
>             (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
>             return confirmationMessage;
>         });
>     }
>
>     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindPageAlert);
> ```

Comment: When i am setting "window.onbeforeunload = null;" after pagination click if i am doing any changes in textbox and withot saving it m navigating to other tab then it doesn't show any messages.

Comment: just make sure after pagination click event, call your javascript again to rebind the script to your page.

Comment: Yes i want that..but how to do that can you plz tell me

Comment: then you need to provide your pagination control as well please

Comment: Sure.... $('.paginationstyle a').click(function (e) {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });    If i am doing this den in pagination click its not showing any message..but how to rebind it again?

Comment: is your pagination control inside an update panel(if it's a web form) or AjaxOptions(if it's MVC) ?

Comment: But still on pagination click its showing the alert message

Comment: Thank you very much.and i got you...can u please update the total code..means where i ll declare the  "window.onbeforeunload = null;" and where again rebind it..i am getting confused.

Comment: your code is inside the update panel, so you just need to make it null the same as before `$('.paginationstyle a').click(function (e) { window.onbeforeunload = null; });` and it will be rebind-ed itself at the end of ajax request.