# Javascript: show Twitter-Bootstrap modal before reload page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reload, onbeforeunload, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to show a modal (with a message and the confirm button) before page reload.

I have to check an array: if it is empty I do the refresh, If it's not I want to show the modal and ask to the user if want to reload.

I tried this code:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
            if(_pendent_annotations.length > 0){
                $('#change_document').modal('show');
                $("#change_doc_button").click(function(){
                                location.reload();
                });
                return false;       
            }

        });
```

The problem is that on reload it shows an `alert` with the message:

> "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?
>
> false"

Then I can choose to leave or to stay, if I choose to leave it reloads if I choose to stay it shows my `modal`.

How can I avoid the alert and only show my modal to make the user choose?

Thanks

Comment: [**This question and answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24117366/1407478) may help you out ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
You need to prevent the event to return anything.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event){
    if(_pendent_annotations.length > 0){
        $('#change_document').modal('show');
        $("#change_doc_button").click(function(){
              location.reload();
        });      
    }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: Sorry I have updated the code you need to remove 
event.returnValue = ''; and return false; lines.
I have checked it. Its working

Comment: Yes I tried also new code, but not working. It's the same of my code, except for `event` as function parameter

Comment: What you have to do the callback function should not return anything. As you are returning false from callback function please remove that as well.

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$(window).addEventListener') ` with your code it throws this error

Comment: you should type $(window).addEventListener();

Not '$(window).addEventListener')

Or you can type only window.addEventListener();

Comment: I copy/paste your code, not changing anything. With `window.addEventListener` it ignore my code (reload always not showing anything), with `$(window).addEventListener` it gives me the error above.